# "to give a bloody for someone"? what does that mean?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

There is a song:

> Fare Three Well (Dink's Song) performed by Marcus Mumford & Oscar
>   Isaac for the movie ''Inside Llewyn Davis''
>   (...)
>
> If I had wings like Noah's dove
>   I'd fly the river to the one that I love
>    Fare three well, my honey fare three well
>
> I had a man, who was long and tall
>   He moved his body like a cannon ball
>    Fare thee well, my honey, fare thee well
>
> I remember one evening in the pouring rain
>   And in my heart there was an aching pain
>   Fare thee well, my honey, fare thee well
>
> Muddy river runs muddy and wild
>   **You can't give a bloody for my unborn child**
>    Fare thee well, my honey, fare thee well
>
> Just as sure as the birds flying high above
>   Life ain't worth living without the one you love
>    Fare thee well, my honey, fare thee well
>
> Fare thee well, my honey, fare thee well

I don't understand the part:

"You can't give a bloody for my unborn child" - what does that mean? I couldn't find anything about such an expression in internet dictionaries.

Comment: They've purposely left out a word for both meter and censoring.  Normally it would be "can't give a bloody damn".  Does that make the meaning clearer?

Comment: Thank you! Much clearer now. I supposed there was something that was left out but didn't know what exactly it could be. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

"Bloody" is a curse word in Britain. It's normally an adjective ('He is a bloody idiot') but seems to be being used as a noun here.

There are some possible ways it could be interpreted. As Hellion suggests, they may have left out a word, with the full version being "bloody damn" or something else. Or alternatively (since "bloody" is a fairly mild curseword) it may be replacing a stronger word such as "You can't give a s***..." or "You can't give a f***...". Alternatively, or as well, scansion may have dictated a substitution.

I don't know who actually wrote the lyrics above ([the original lyrics of the song don't contain that line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dink%27s_Song)). If it was written for the movie then audience sensibilities may have dictated the line. The song was recorded by different artists, many long enough ago that putting in a stronger curseword would have been out of the question.

The original lyrics certainly are such that "You can't give a **** for my unborn child" would have fitted well in. They are less direct but the intention is clearly the same.